# Android InApp Billing gives RESULT_ERROR most of the time

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm having severe problems with my IAP integration. Analytics show these stats:

- RESULT_CANCELLED: 3432
- RESULT_ERROR: 374
- RESULT_OK: 11

I understand those RESULT_CANCELLED events but why are there so many RESULT_ERROR events?

Also when I just tried to put in some debug information I'm very confused since I cannot find the place that gives me some information about what the actual error was.

I'm using the IAP example code from Google.

So, any idea where to look for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are experiencing the same issue we tried to isolate the flows and see what was the reason for this behavior.

Although we do not have a good explanation for the high error rate we did find that on many cases the android market app returns RESULT_ERROR when there's no connectivity instead of the expected RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE (wtf!?)

I'll update as soon as we have more data

Best, Zvi

Comment: really looking forward to your results, keep us posted :)